# What is the correct way to obtain the class object for class List without losing type information?

Tags: java, generics, generic-collections, unbounded-wildcard

As a preface to my question, please note that I know what type erasure is. I feel the need to state this so useful answers don't get buried in basic explanations.

I would like to obtain the class object for class List. For a non-generic type, I would use a class literal like String.class, but for List, even though I can obtain the correct behavior, I still get warnings that I am doing it wrong.

From my understanding, the class object for List would be of type `Class<List>`, but even writing down that type,

```
Class<List> c = null;
```

gives a warning: "Raw use of parameterized class 'List'". Due to type erasure, the class object cannot have knowledge about list elements, so my next guess would be

```
Class<List<?>> c = null;
```

which as a type gets accepted. Next I have to obtain the class object, but every way of trying to write down a class literal fails:

```
Class<List<?>> l = List.class;
```

gives a hard type error, while

```
Class<List<?>> l = List<?>.class;
```

says "Cannot select from parameterized type".

```
Class<List<?>> l = (Class<List>)List.class;
```

Fails with the same hard type error as without the cast (expected since the cast is redundant), and

```
Class<List<?>> l = (Class<List<?>>)List.class;
```

says "inconvertible types".

Next, I tried the following invalid code snippet to learn something from the compiler error:

```
List<?> l = new ArrayList<>();
int x = l.getClass();
```

Now the compiler gives a type error for `Class<? extends java.util.List>` -- ignoring the "extends" part for a moment, which is obvious since `getClass()` could return a subclass, this tells me that `.getClass()` only wants to talk about the raw List type, not `List<?>` or similar. In a way, that seems correct to me, since the class object represents any List instance, not "lists whose type is unknown". However, I'm back to square one now because just writing down the raw type gives a warning, so I'm obviously not expected to do that (I understand that raw types can be used to deal with legacy code, but I'm not doing that here).

I understand that I could throw away all static type information about the class object like this:

```
Class<?> c = List.class;
```

But this is often not feasible, and indeed I'm trying to solve a larger problem where I need that type information.

While I know that I can easily disable warnings or use similar dirty tricks, I would like to know what the correct way is to obtain the class object for List.

Comment: You can't. `List` **is** the class. The class has no generic type information.

Comment: "*I understand that I could throw away all static type information about the class*" It's not a matter of 'could'. There isn't anything to throw away.

Comment: "I'm trying to solve a larger problem where I need that type information." Then you need to explain **that** problem. As said, you can't have a `Class`. But you *could* have a e.g. `TypeReference`, however as you haven't explained your problem, we don't know if that will help you.

Comment: Exactly as @Michael said. Maybe this is an XY problem?

Comment: "There isn't anything to throw away" -- yes there is, namely that the class is (a subtype of) java.util.List -- by using Class<?>, I would throw that away, but this creates follow-up problems.

Comment: There should not be a need to explain the larger problem. The question how to correctly obtain a class object in a language where this is considered a built-in feature can stand on its own.

Comment: If what I am trying to do is impossible because of a limitation of generics, then just describing that limitation is a perfectly acceptable answer. Just claiming that I don't understand generics is not. Likewise, if you think that the question cannot be understood without more context, you should be able to explain why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way you can win this war.

There is no such thing as an instance of `Class<List<?>>`, or whatever. That's a valid *type*, but there is no concrete value that you can assign to that (other than `null`), because `List.class` and `new ArrayList<>().getClass()` have type `Class<List>` and `Class<? extends List>` respectively.

Class instances are inherently raw-typed, because of type erasure.

You *can* do unchecked casts:

```
Class<List<?>> clazz = (Class<List<?>>) (Class<?>) List.class;
```

but that will also generate warnings; and since you can do other unsafe casts, like:

```
Class<List<?>> clazz1 = (Class<List<?>>) (Class<?>) ArrayList.class;
```

you might end up in an odd situation where two instances of `Class<List<?>>` are unequal, or for example that sometimes a `Class<List<?>>` can be instantiated (using `clazz.newInstance()`), and other times not.

---

Now, if you need some sort of generic type token, you can use something like what Guice does:

```
TypeLiteral<ArrayList<?>> typeLiteral =
    new TypeLiteral<ArrayList<?>>() {};
```

It *is* possible to obtain the `ArrayList<?>` from that at runtime, because of the way the superclass is captured (note the `{}` - this is an anonymous subclass of `TypeLiteral`). You can implement this yourself quite easily if you don't want to take a dependency on Guice (or other libraries which offer similar constructs), using `typeLiteral.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()`.

But whether that is an approach you can take depends on your undisclosed problem. The key takeaway is that generics and reflection just don't play nicely together.

Comment: The element type is irrelevant to me, which is why I didn't even consider type tokens. The part of your answer where you say that List.class has type Class<List> is going in the right direction, but why is (Class<List> c = List.class) wrong then?

Comment: It's "wrong" because it's a raw type, which should generally be avoided, and there is no specialization of the warning (in whatever is giving you that warning) between e.g. `List<List>` and `Class<List>`.

Comment: In your answer you said that List.class has type Class<List>, but then raw types should be avoided... are you trying to say that using the class objects of a parameterized type is discouraged in general?

Comment: That is what I mean by my last sentence, yes.